# Modify the json file for Tasks Collection in Azure Batch

Tags: azure, task, multitasking, azure-batch

I am trying to modify a json file for allowing the Azure Batch to perform a Collection of Tasks (lets say 100 per submission) when submitting them. Below is the current file:

````
  "name": "....",
  "vmSize": "....",
  "maxTasksPerNode": 2,
  "poolSize": {
    "dedicatedNodes": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 0
    },
    "lowPriorityNodes": {
      "min": 30,
      "max": 50
    },
    "autoscaleFormula": "QUEUE"
  },
  "rPackages": {
    "cran": ["...", "..."],
    "github": [],
    "bioconductor": []
  },
  "commandLine": [],
  "subnetId": ""
} ```

Do you have any idea how to modify this? Thank you.
````

Comment: Could you specify what SDK/Tool/Environment you are using to submit your tasks? Generally speaking the process is to create a Pool of VMs, then create a Job(container) for the tasks, and then you can use an AddTasks API to add tasks to that job. Once more context is given, an answer may be able to be given.

Comment: Hi. I am using R to submit the tasks. My command looks like that:


results_list <- foreach (i=1:nrow(...), .options.azure = list(enableCloudCombine = FALSE, wait = FALSE, autoDeleteJob = FALSE), .errorhandling = "pass")
 %dopar% { myfunction(....) }

The job runs fine. The only issue that I have is that I would it to submit them 100 by 100 instead of 1 by 1 each time. This will speed-up my submission time. My question is how can I achieve that?